# Is it possible to use T2 Unlimited instances in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use T2 Unlimited instances with Elastic Beanstalk. I don't want to configure this after the instances have launched, so I am wondering if anyone knows if it's at all possible with EB configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. Posting it here in case others run into the same issue:

1. Create an IAM policy that allows the ec2 instances in your elastic beanstalk environment to modify instance credit specification and attach it to your elastic beanstalk ec2 role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "InstanceCreditPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceCreditSpecification",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceCreditSpecifications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create an eb extension (`.ebextensions/01-set-instance-credit-unlimited.config`)

```
commands:
  set-instance-credit-unlimited:
    command: |
      aws ec2 modify-instance-credit-specification --region <your_region> --instance-credit-specification '[{"InstanceId": "'"$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)"'","CpuCredits": "unlimited"}]'
```

Comment: it's working but I changed the command because the instance id is not returned successfully.. 

`aws ec2 modify-instance-credit-specification --region eu-west-3 --instance-credit-specification '[{\"InstanceId\": \"'\"$(ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d \" \" -f 2)\"'\",\"CpuCredits\": \"unlimited\"}]'"`

This Command worked with me, I just replace `$(wget -q -O - 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)` with `$(ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d \" \" -f 2)`

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using solution stack- "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.1.1 running Node.js", in addition to creating the policy described by user **steinim**, you need to use these two config files instead:

1) upgrade-awscli.config

```
commands: 
  modify-instance-credit-specification:
    command: "sudo pip install --upgrade awscli"
```

2) t2-unlimited-test.config

```
commands: 
  modify-instance-credit-specification:
    command: "aws ec2 modify-instance-credit-specification --region us-west-2 --instance-credit-specification '[{\"InstanceId\": \"'\"$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)\"'\",\"CpuCredits\": \"unlimited\"}]'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this myself, but have noticed that t3 EC2 instances have unlimited mode enabled by default [1][2], as well as being cheaper than t2 instances.  Therefore, if you use a t3 instance type in your EB env, you're good to go, with no additional EB env configuration required.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-t3-instances-burstable-cost-effective-performance/

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the PowerShell version of @steinim's answer, this is it:

```
$InstanceID = wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id -UseBasicParsing
$Credit = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceCreditSpecificationRequest
$Credit.InstanceId = $InstanceID
$Credit.CpuCredits = "unlimited"
Edit-EC2InstanceCreditSpecification -InstanceCreditSpecification $Credit
```

So your `.ebextensions/01-set-instance-credit-unlimited.config` file will look like this:

```
files:
  "c:/scripts/Enable-T2Unlimited.ps1":
    content: |
      Import-Module AWSPowerShell
      $InstanceID = wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id -UseBasicParsing
      $Credit = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceCreditSpecificationRequest
      $Credit.InstanceId = $InstanceID
      $Credit.CpuCredits = "unlimited"
      Edit-EC2InstanceCreditSpecification -InstanceCreditSpecification $Credit
commands:
  01_Enable_T2_Unlimited:
    command: powershell c:\\scripts\\Enable-T2Unlimited.ps1
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
```